# Making a query for two tables for the abusive words analytics

Tags: mysql, sql

I do a chat analyzer with statistics on the used abusive words and the corresponding rating.

Table structure:

Messages: id - unique message ID, from_id - sender ID, date — date of sending, text - text.

Offensive:

id - the unique ID of the abusive word found in the message, type — the numerical value associated with the root of the abusive word, from_id — ID of the sender (the same as in Messages), in_message — ID of the message in which this abusive word is used, text — the abusive word itself.

Next, I do the following query to build a top of potty mouth guys:

```
SELECT from_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM `Offensive` 
GROUP BY from_id 
ORDER BY `COUNT(*)` DESC
```

However, the cheaters started to write messages like «fuck fuck fuck fuck». to boost his rating. I think that I can sift through that kind of cheating, by building a rating using query, that not considering more than a certain number of abusive words in N amount of time, but, unfortunately, I don't know how to do it...

I also have tried this:

```
SELECT from_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT count(*), from_id, in_message 
  FROM `Offensive` 
  GROUP BY in_message 
  HAVING `count(*)`<100
) AS lol 
GROUP BY from_id 
ORDER BY `COUNT(*)` DESC
```

— not to consider the messages that having more than a certain number of abusive words, but in this case it just takes no more than one abusive word per message

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
https://gist.github.com/kolyanok/10f976a3d60e9a35e6b5c1416db5d753

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kolyanok/10f976a3d60e9a35e6b5c1416db5d753 here is a sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count the number of *different* abusive words.  I think this might do it:

```
SELECT from_id, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM Offensive
GROUP BY from_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

If you want more refined limits, such as "5" for each word:

```
select from_id, sum(case when num <= 5 then num else 5 end)
from (select from_id, id, count(*) as num
      from offensive
      group by from_id, id
     ) o
group by from_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems like you’re didn’t understood me :(

Cheating is not the use the same abusive words, but it's using of a large number of swear words in a single message, or, ideally, in multiple messages over a short period of time.